# Bash script to automate codec installation

Tags: bash, scripts, regex

I recently moved from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.  I don't keep any media files but when I visited youtube I discovered no audio was playing. After some time I came to (guided)conclusion that I need to install codecs. But after I used grep on apt list there are one too many and I'm uncertain which ones to choose. So I was wondering if I could filter all these results with regex and somehow automate the installation without having to individually install each codec or go through trial and error to find which one fixes the sound for me.
ps- I did the troubleshooting as told by official site viz check connections,sound card etc.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you don't need to install *all* codecs.

Generally, I always install the most common ones with:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

which contains mp4 among others.

Additionally, you can use:

```
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra
```

which contains additional codecs for `ffmpeg` if that is of interest to you.